# What should I do if I forgot to pray Fajr on Friday?

Tags: salat, salat-qada, fajr

I didn't wake up for the Fajr of Friday as I was sick, then forgot to pray it after I woke up and prayed the Jumuaa (Friday) prayer. What should I do?

Comment: Oops, asking such nice questions can be investigate as a constructive which can be the problem of many Muslims... , particularly concerning the salah-al-Fajr as you nicely pointed that out ( due to its soon times that perhaps ...)

Answer (score 2):

```
             In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

What you have inquired can be investigated as indeed a helpful question for the readers, since this issue can be occurred for many of Muslims, especially for the Fajr prayers (because of its time…). As you asked:

> I didn't wake up for the Fajr of Friday as I was sick, then forgot to
>   pray it after I woke up and prayed the Jumuaa (Friday) prayer. What
>   should I do?

In order to respond to you in short, it is declared that… you are free in your choice... Although it is nicer to say your Fajr-Qaza Salat (prayer) before the Salat of Zuhur, but you can change your Niah (intention) to the Salat-al-Fajr during the Salat-al-Zuhur (if you remembered it during the Salat-al-Zuhur (probably it can has the same term for both Zuhur or Jum’a Salah; and Allah Knows Best). Accordingly, you are able to change your Niat (intention) to the Fajr-Qaza-Salat (if you’d like). Otherwise you can leave it till afterwards… then do its Qaza.

---

**Reference:**
[www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/01049/)

Answer (score 0):

You pray Al Fajr, now this is Saudi Sheikh fatwa,

[http://fatwa.islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/36575)

The argument is about what did the Prophet (peace be upon him) said "One who forgets his prayer and then he makes it when he remembers".

Answer (score 0):

As much as I searched, I inferred from the sources below that it is better or even you should offer the Qaza of your Fajr prayer before the prayer of Zuhr (of that day). Anyway, you should repeat that Fajr prayer that you forgot to say it whenever you can. So you'd better say your qaza prayer as soon as possible.

**Source:**

- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/3475#gsc.tab=0)
- [www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/01049/)